# Specific devices to gain access to page, but others cannot

Tags: java, php, html, mysql, qr-code

I have a project in mind, but i was hoping i could get some insight.

Would it be possible to have a page allow access to my phone, or a co workers phone or laptop or device, but refuse any other device to gain access to this page.
The idea of this project is through QR codes, for example,

If i generate a QR code, to access a list of lets say, inventory. i would like my phone, or my co workers phone to gain access to it, but if say my brother or someone outside trys the code and gets sent to this specific page(s), it doesn't allow it to happen because the phone ID or tablet ID is not in the list to gain access.

It would be difficult to create a login page and enable QR codes, because you cannot implement the login information in the QR code because then the security would be irrelevant.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

Your page could restrict access based on the originating IP address.  The feasibility of such a system would depend on a number of parameters, such as whether you are connecting over wifi or cellular, in the case of wifi - whether you trust the wifi network, in the case of cellular - how often the cell provider changes your address.

A better solution might be to use a custom URI scheme and a custom app installed on only the phones and tablets that you want to have access.  When the device scans the QR code, the app would handle the request, and then log in to the web site over HTTPS with proper authentication.  e.g.

QR code:  my.app://blah/blah
App handles URL, logs into server, redirects to https://my.site/blah/blah

Comment: i was afraid that would be the only options.. i wanted something pretty simple.. and unfortunately time is what we dont have. i like the idea of the ip address, could we not use the same as MAC address on the device?

Comment: MAC addresses are network-local.  Unless everyone is on the same WIFI network that's not going to work.

Comment: ...and if the server and all the clients are on the same WIFI network, you might as well use IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use identity certificates? Sign your message (QR Code) with the corresponding private key and validate for scanner's Identity, Trust and Message integrity.

Comment: how would i go around doing this? wouldnt it be with a custom app?